# How to sync data with android wear 2.0 (standalone apk)

Tags: android, android-wear-2.0

I want to publish android wear2.0(standalone) apk to the playstore.My phone app is already published on the playstore with wear1.0.4 embedded apk.
Right now I am running wear2.0 apk on emulator for testing.
But I have no clue how to sync it with my android phone(without using bluetooth) or an iphone.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as Wear 1.0. The way I've been publishing the phone app and the wear app is that my wear app's version code is one higher than the phone app but since it differentiates by feature (watch), both are on the Play store simultaneously. The embedded apk for wear 1.0 goes to the watch with the phone app but wear 2.0 watches show a notification for the user to download your (wear 2.0) app from the watch play store.

As long as the package names are the same, you can sync data using the Data APIs. Less recommended but since the watch has Internet now, you can even sync in other ways.